# Cannot create key bindings with the pipe-key on my Norwegian keyboard in Sublime Text 2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, json

I am trying to bind `ctrl+|` to `Show Console` in Sublime Text 2 on a Norwegian keyboard using the following line in the (json?) configuration file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+|"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },
```

This doesn't work, and the pipe symbol also has a slightly darker tint than the rest of the configuration text, as if it is special.

I tried to escape it using `"ctrl+\|"` and `"ctrl+\\|"` none of which work. Binding it to something else like `"ctrl+p"` works fine.

Any idea of how to bind functionality with the pipe-key? It's the top left key on the keyboard, left to the `1` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the question over at the sublime text forum. The user [mlf](https://forum.sublimetext.com/u/mlf) gave me [the answer](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16477#p62066) which lead me to [the solution](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16477#p67663):

Manually open the console: View -> Show Console

Enter `sublime.log_input(True)` then hit the key combination `ctrl+|`.

This produces the output `chr evt: FS (0x1c)`. Here `FS` stands in for the [File Separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) character. You can produce it using `alt+028` on the numpad in Windows.

Enter/past it into key bindings config file. It should look like the following:

```
{ "keys": ["FS"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },
```

Note that you cannot simply copy-paste the above line, you have to actually paste/produce the `FS` character yourself.

When done you can turn logging of with the command `sublime.log_input(False)` in the console.

Comment: To add more clarity for people with Nordic keyboards, the File Separator character is protected in Sublime Text, which means you need to escape it with another File Separator. 

So to use ctrl + "Key next to 1" on your Nordic keyboard you use:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+\\"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }`

Answer (score 1):

Answer is similar as André except that it didn't show the same "FS" character. For me it is showing "<0x1c>", which I thought was a simple string at the beginning but is actually the representation of the ASCII code.

When doing `sublime.log_input(True)` in the console, it shows `chr evt: <0x1c> (0x1c)` when I type `ctrl + |`. I just had to copy this `<0x1c>` ASCII code from the console (not a string), and paste it to my keybindings config file :

`{ "keys": ["*<0x1c>*"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the pipe symbol <kbd>|</kbd> is not one of Sublime's [bindable keys](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys), even on a US keyboard.

Comment: If this is the case, and there are no workarounds, then this is a bug. Because letting me bind the so called "tilde" key to functionality is expected functionality from a $70 software.